# Average of specific group of values

Tags: sql, join, select, subquery, average

I am trying to select the average age of renters of a specific movie for demographic purposes.

My data is similar to

```
Movies
movie_id    movie_title
1           Spider Man
2           Avengers
3           Thor
```

```
Customers
customer_id    customer_dob
1              1989-03-05
2              1994-02-12
3              2001-05-01
```

```
Customer_rentals
rental_id    customer_id    movie_id
1            1              1
2            1              3
3            2              2
4            2              1
5            3              1
```

What I would like to see is

```
Title        Avg_Age
Spider Man   25
Avengers     26
Thor         31
```

I have tried the following

```
select m.movie_title as Title, avg(all_ages.age) as avg_age
from
    movies m,
    (select ((0 + convert(char(8), getdate(),112) - convert(char(8),c.customer_dob,112)) / 10000) as age
    from customers c, movies m, customer_rentals cr
    where m.movie_id=cr.movie_id
    and cr.customer_id=c.customer_id) all_ages
group by m.movie_title
```

Which gives me

```
Title         Avg_Age
Spider Man    25
Avengers      25
Thor          25
```

It seems to be taking the average of all ages and returning it as the average for each movie and I'm not sure why this is happening

Comment: You need the date when they rented the movie.  There is little value in looking at the current age when they may have rented the movie years ago.

Comment: Ok sure that's a good point about the design here, but it doesn't really answer my question. For the sake of the question, please assume that all rentals have happened, are happening, and will happen on today's date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your query is that the subquery is not properly correlated to the outer query. You are selecting again from `movie` (using the same alias as in the outer query - `m` - which is confusing), while you should be relating to the record from outer query.

This can be simplified with straight joins and aggregation:

```
select 
    m.movie_title as Title, 
    avg((0 + convert(char(8), getdate(),112) - convert(char(8),c.customer_dob,112)) / 10000) as avg_age
from movies m
inner join customer_rentals cr on cr.movie_id = m.movie_id 
inner join customers c         on c.customer_id = cr.customer_id
group by m.movie_id, m.movie_title
```

Note that this uses *standard*, explicit joins (with the `on` keyword) rather than implicit joins (with commas in the `from` clause): this old syntax from decades ago should not be used in new code.

Comment: Thank you so much!